# DigitalOcean Tomcat Setup

Tags: java, tomcat

I finished following this Digital Ocean tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04

Everything went ok and my Tomcat service is running.

The only problem is that I cannot access my tomcat web site as it says.

When I type in the browser: http://MY-IP:8080/

I get this in Firefox:

```
Unable to connect
```

If I do a wget http://MY-IP:8080 I get this on my home computer:

```
--2015-06-26 22:09:37--  http://MY-IP:8080/
Connecting to MY-IP:8080... failed: Connection refused.
```

This is a brand new fresh Ubuntu image 14.04, and I only have java and tomcat on it.
It is my first time setting up Tomcat.
Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Are you also hosted on DigitalOcean?

Comment: FYI, saying "Apache" usually makes people think of the original [Apache httpd web server](http://httpd.apache.org) project. For Tomcat, either say "Tomcat" or "Apache Tomcat". I edited your title accordingly.

Comment: GOT IT! I was using java 6 instead of java 7

Answer (score 2):

Run this command to check on the status of Tomcat:

```
sudo service tomcat status
```

If Tomcat's status is running, check which port with this:

```
netstat -anp | grep tomcat
```

You can also just check if anything is running on port 8080 with this:

```
netstat -a | grep 8080
```

Let us know the results of that.

Comment: hello, thanks for the quick response. I get this 'tomcat stop/waiting' from the 'sudo service tomcat status'. All the others return nothing/empty.

Comment: GOT IT! I was using java 6 instead of java 7

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help!